# Aspect oriented question - Pointcut

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

i'm wondering what the following means in a pointcut

```
after(FigureElement fe, int x, int y) returning:
        call(void FigureElement.setXY(int, int))
        && target(fe)
        && args(x, y) {
    System.out.println(fe + " moved to (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
}
```

what does target and args mean here? i've no idea.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look to the [AspectJ guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html).

> **target(Type or Id)**     every join point when the target executing object is an instance of Type or Id's type
>
> **args(Type or Id, ...)**  every join point when the arguments are instances of Types or the types of the Ids

In your example, for pointcut to match, the method must be called on `FigureElement` instances and have two `int` arguments. Names given as `target` and `args` parameters means that those parameters are accessible inside your advice body.

So, your pointcut matches all calls to `FigureElement.setXY` method with two `int` arguments and gives you access to the matched instance as `fe` and method arguments as `x` and `y`.